# Automatic audio device switch turned off accidentally

Tags: windows-7, audio

My computer used to switch from the monitor speaker to my headset whenever I plugged the last one. Yesterday, I may have changed accidentally some options in the RealTek HD Audio manager and now it won't switch unless I keep setting the devices to default manually. Nothing else has changed, so how can I enable the automatic switching again?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in RealTek HD Audio Manager.

[image: RealTek HD Audio Manager]